# Android CTS 7.0 failed any plan or module

Tags: android

I have just build and installed NRD90U on Nexus 6P. Now I am trying to run the CTS. I have downloaded the Android 7.0 R4 Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) - ARM and copied the media files to the device.

For CTS 7.0 I have installed (`adb install -r android-cts/testcases/CtsAdminApp.apk`) this as helper and configured android.deviceadmin.cts.CtsDeviceAdminReceiver* under: "Settings >
 Security > Select device administrators".

When I am trying to run CTS (`run cts --plan <plan name>`) I am getting
this error:

> "E/TestInvocation: Caught exception while running invocation
>   "E/TestInvocation: Not all target preparation steps completed"
>   android.tradefed.targetprep.TargerSetupError:Not all Target
>   Preparation steps completed.
>   com.android.complatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.APKInstrumentPreparer.run
>   (APKInstrumentPreparer.java)
>   com.android.complatibility.common.tradefed.targetprep.DeviceInfoCollector.setup(DeviceInfoCollector.java)
>   com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.com.android.(TestInvocation.java)
>   . . . :Invocation failed:
>   com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError:Not all target
>   preparation steps completed"

Can anybody please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

CTS 7.0 run plan only run the specified test plan. You can use command "l p" show all the plans. If you want to see the detail about plan, you can check android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed.jar, open it and under config there are test plans' configration file.

If you want to run one test case, you can ‘l m’, get all the modules.
Detailed see :https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/run.html